# Having issues searching through file and replacing

Tags: ruby

I'm having a bit of trouble searching through a file and editing certain parameters of the file. The code is below

```
file_names = ["#{fileNameFromUser}"]

file_names.each do |file_name|
 text = File.read(file_name)
 replacedcontent = text.gsub(/textToReplace/, "#{ReplaceWithThis}")
 replacedcontent += text.gsub(/textToReplace2/, "#{ReplaceWithThis2}")

# To write changes to the file, use:
File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts replacedcontent}
end
```

so right now what it does is that it print the contents of the file twice and I can only assume its because its inside the `do` loop. My end goal here is that the file has `textToReplace` and `textToReplace2` and I need it to read through the file, replaced both with whatever the user inputs and save/write changes to the file.

Comment: `"#{fileNameFromUser}"` is same as `fileNameFromUser.clone`, but the latter is easier to read. But I see no need in your code for cloning, since the strings are not being mutated; so `fileNameFromUser` should suffice, no?

Comment: If the file contains `12` initially and the replacements are `1 => 2` and `2 => 3`, should the final result be `23` or `33`?

Answer (score 2):

> it print the contents of the file twice and I can only assume its because its inside the `do` loop

Nope, it's because you append it twice:

```
text = first_replacement_result
text += second_replacement_result
```

There's two ways to do this: one with mutation:

```
text.gsub!(...) # first replacement that changes `text`
text.gsub!(...) # second replacement that changes `text` again
```

or chained replacement:

```
replacedcontent = text.gsub(...).gsub(...) # two replacements one after another
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re-use `replacedcontent` instead of concatenating it to avoid printing it twice.

```
file_names = ["#{fileNameFromUser}"]

file_names.each do |file_name|
text = File.read(file_name)
replacedcontent = text.gsub(/textToReplace/, "#{ReplaceWithThis}")
replacedcontent = replacedcontent.gsub(/textToReplace2/, "#{ReplaceWithThis2}")

# To write changes to the file, use:
File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts replacedcontent}
end
```

OR

```
replacedcontent = text.gsub(/textToReplace/, "#{ReplaceWithThis}").gsub(/textToReplace2/, "#{ReplaceWithThis2}")
```